# systemd - .service default parameters

Tags: systemd, services

I'm replacing our old `init.d` Glassfish script with a `.service` file.
I want the ability to start/stop domains one by one, but also a quick way to start/stop all of them at once.

So far, I have this as `glassfish@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Glassfish4 Domain %i

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin --passwordfile /my/pw/file start-domain %i
ExecStop=/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin --passwordfile /my/pw/file stop-domain %i

TimeoutStartSec=300
TimeoutStopSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This works and I can start, stop and enable a single domain like this:

```
systemctl start glassfish@domain1
```

However, I would also like to be able to stop or start **all** the domains like this:

```
systemctl stop glassfish
```

How can I achieve this? Also, how can I show the status of each instance of `glassfish@.service`?

I'm currently thinking of writing a script which is called from the `.service` file and actually starts/stops the domains, using a default set of parameters if none are supplied. But this feels hacky and wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

`systemd` apparently supports wildcards. So once you have enabled some instances, you can easily stop all of them like this:

```
systemctl stop 'glassfish@*'
```

Apparently, Ubuntu requires you to add a `--all`, so the total command is

```
systemctl stop 'glassfish@*' --all
```